# Internet explorer 11 temporary files located at

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I would like to know where temporary files and/or cache is setup on a Windows 7 or windows 10 workstation when internet explorer 11 is being used? I would like to also know if these temporary files and cache locations can be removed and/or cleared out. 
I want to clear out these areas so that I have more room on my 'C' drive of the computer to work with.

Thus would you tell me where these locations are at and how can I delete the files?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to run the Disk Cleanup tool that comes with Windows.
You can search for it in the start menu or right click your main drive in Explorer, select properties and hit the Disk Cleanup button.
Temporary Internet files is one of the things it cleans up.

Comment: I have done disk cleanup. Thus you are saying that all the temporary files for internet explorer 11 clears out all these temporary locations, correct?